# Two trees and a joint table between them

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I have three tables: two hierarchical tables and one junction between these.

```
Teams
id  idParent
1   null
2   1
3   null
4   null
5   4

Projects
id  idParent
1   null
2   null
3   2
4   2
5   null

TeamProjects
idTeam  idProject
2       2
3       1
5       5
```

A project always depend on at least one team, this is what teamprojects is for.

The result I'm trying to achieve: for each of the object (both teams and projects), I want to know what are the ascendant and descendant objects (id concatened)

```
idObject    ascendantTeams  descendantTeam  ascendantProjects   descendantProjects
1                                   2                               7, 10
2            1                                                      7
3                                                                   6
4               
5            4                                                      10
6            3          
7            2                                                      8, 9
8            2                                  7   
9            2                                  7   
10           5
```

I am trying to achieve this with a linq to entities query, but i need both CTE (for the recursive part) and (stuff-for-xml) for the concatenation part... and neither translate to linq to entities.
so i'm trying to make a view to help, but i dont manage to write the sql for it either.

How would you resolve this, either with linq to entities or sql?

Comment: Please make this to the point. I think the recursive query is the main stumbling block. *Show your own attempts* and focus on getting that right. (Which makes this a SQL question only).

Comment: What does `idObject` in your final result mean? Is it id from teams or projects table?

Comment: yes, idObject can have a value from both tables

Comment: If a team has no parent or child then its projects come under descendantProjects?

Comment: yes absolutely, any project whom parent is this team will be the descendantProjects of this team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not very clear.

So, I have made some assumptions in order to come up with the solution. I have assumed that a project will be included in descendantProjects for team-based result ( see `dbo.GetProjectsForTeam`), and a team will be included in descendantTeams for project-based result( see `dbo.GetTeamsForProject`). This was not at all clear from your question.

You will need to create scalar-valued functions to achieve your scenario.

**How scalar valued functions are called**

*Each of these functions takes two parameters -  a type parameter that will be `a` for ascendants or `d` for descendants, and the id that will be team id for team-based query or project id for project-based query*.

**Team Related Scalar Valued functions**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTeamsForTeam](
               @teamType VARCHAR(20) , --either 'a' for ascendants or 'd' for descendants
               @teamId   INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX);
         IF @teamType = 'a'
             BEGIN
                 --get all parent teams
                 SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+','+CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                 WHERE t.Id IN ( SELECT t2.IdParent
                                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t2
                                 WHERE t2.id = @teamId
                               );
             END;
         ELSE
             BEGIN
                 --get all children teams including @teamId
                 SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+','+CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                 WHERE t.Id IN ( SELECT t2.Id
                                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t2
                                 WHERE t2.IdParent = @teamId
                                       OR
                                       t2.Id = @teamId
                               );
             END;
         RETURN @list;
     END;
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProjectsForTeam](
               @projectType VARCHAR(1) , --either 'a' for ascendants or 'd' for descendants
               @teamId       INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @projects VARCHAR(MAX);
         IF @projectType = 'a'
             BEGIN
                 --get projects for all the parents of @teamId
                 SELECT @projects = COALESCE(@projects+','+CAST(tp.idProject AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(tp.idProject AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.TeamProjects AS tp
                 WHERE tp.idTeam IN ( SELECT t.IdParent
                                      FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                                      WHERE t.Id = @teamId
                                    );
             END;
         ELSE
             BEGIN
                 --get projects for all children of @teamId including @teamId
                 SELECT @projects = COALESCE(@projects+','+CAST(tp.idProject AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(tp.idProject AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.TeamProjects AS tp
                 WHERE tp.idTeam IN ( SELECT t.Id
                                      FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                                      WHERE t.IdParent = @teamId OR t.Id = @teamId
                                    );
             END;
         RETURN @projects;
     END;
GO
```

Using the above scalar-valued functions, the team-based query to achieve your final result set is as below.

```
SELECT t.id AS TeamId,
       dbo.GetTeamsForTeam('a', t.id) AS ascendantTeams,
       dbo.GetTeamsForTeam('d', t.id) AS descendantTeams,
       dbo.GetProjectsForTeam('a', t.id) AS ascendantProjects,
       dbo.GetProjectsForTeam('d', t.id) AS descendantProjects
FROM Teams t;
```

**Project Related Scalar Valued functions**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTeamsForProject] (
                @teamType  VARCHAR(20) , --either 'a' for ascendants or 'd' for descendants
                @projectId INT
                                           )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX);
         IF @teamType = 'a'
             BEGIN
                 --get all parent teams
                 SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+','+CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                 WHERE t.Id IN ( SELECT t2.IdParent
                                 FROM dbo.Projects AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TeamProjects AS tp ON p.Id = tp.idProject
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Teams AS t2 ON t2.id = tp.idTeam
                                 WHERE p.id = @projectId
                               );
             END;
         ELSE
             BEGIN
                 --get all children teams including team for @projectId
                 SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+','+CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(t.Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Teams AS t
                 WHERE t.Id IN ( SELECT t2.Id
                                 FROM dbo.Projects AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TeamProjects AS tp ON p.Id = tp.idProject
                                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Teams AS t2 ON t2.id = tp.idTeam
                                 WHERE p.IdParent = @projectId OR p.Id = @projectId 
                               );
             END;
         RETURN @list;
     END;

GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProjectsForProject] (
                @projectType VARCHAR(1) , --either 'a' for ascendants or 'd' for descendants
                @projectId   INT
                                              )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @projects VARCHAR(MAX);
         IF @projectType = 'a'
             BEGIN
                 --get projects for all the parents of @projectId
                 SELECT @projects = COALESCE(@projects+','+CAST(p.idParent AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(p.idParent AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Projects AS p
                 WHERE p.Id IN ( SELECT p.IdParent
                                 FROM dbo.Projects AS p
                                 WHERE p.Id = @projectId
                               );
             END;
         ELSE
             BEGIN
                 --get projects for all children of @projectd
                 SELECT @projects = COALESCE(@projects+','+CAST(p.id AS VARCHAR(10)) , CAST(p.id AS VARCHAR(10)))
                 FROM dbo.Projects AS p
                 WHERE p.IdParent IN ( SELECT p.Id
                                       FROM dbo.Projects AS p
                                       WHERE p.IdParent = @projectId OR p.Id = @projectId     
                                     );
             END;
         RETURN @projects;
     END;

GO
```

Using the above project-based functions, the query for project-based query would be as below.

```
SELECT p.id AS ProjectId,
       dbo.GetTeamsForProject('a', p.id) AS ascendantTeams,
       dbo.GetTeamsForProject('d', p.id) AS descendantTeams,
       dbo.GetProjectsForProject('a', p.id) AS ascendantProjects,
       dbo.GetProjectsForProject('a', p.id) AS descendantProjects
FROM dbo.Projects p;
```

A screen shot of sample data I used and the final queries is as given below.

[image: Screen shot of Sample Data with Results]

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's late here i will check it and validate if it's Ok in the morning